# Can I enable a `$DB::single =1` breakpoint conditionally from a program?

Tags: perl, debugging, conditional-breakpoint

I have a case where a local variable in a `sub` has the wrong un-blessed value after several invocations, and I'd like to break to the Perl debugger (when the program runs under debugger control, of course) if a specific condition is met.

I could try a conditional breakpoint interactively, but that would be a lot of typing work when repeating the "modify, debug" cycle many times.

Anyway I'd like to know whether its possible to use a construct like `$DB::single=1 if (...);`.
When I tried it, it did not work, and the breakpoint was active all the time.

So is it possible?

### What I had tried

Basically my problem is that the line `@l_socks = @{$lsa->sockets()};` triggered a "*Can't call "sockets" on unblessed reference at ...*".
As the code is in a subroutine that is called many times before the problem happens, I added `$DB::single = 1 unless (ref $lsa);` before the problematic line, but that did not work.

So maybe my problem is that `$lsa` is not a scalar as expected, but a reference; unblesswd however.

Comment: Yes, but `$DB::single = ...;` would suffice. /// Re "*When I tried it, it did not work*", We can't tell what you did wrong if you don't show us. Please add a minimal, runable demonstration of the problem.

Comment: It turns out I don't know how to check the blessed-ness correctly: `$x->isa('foo')` returns the empty string if `$x` is a scalar (like `42`), but it fails with "**Can't call method "isa" on unblessed reference**..." when `$x` is an `ARRAY` reference. Seems I have to use `UNIVERSAL::isa($x, 'foo')` instead.

Comment: No, Scalar::Util's `blessed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For completeness, here is the "answer" to my question:

`$DB::single = 1` correctly enables a debugger breakpoint after the instruction following the command **if** the condition to trigger it is correct.

In my case I used an incorrect condition that would never trigger, so it seemed the `$DB::single = 1` was ignored.

Fixing the condition fixed the problem.
For the code example shown (you are not expected to understand the details; `SocketArray` is a package written for this program), using

```perl
unless (UNIVERSAL::isa($lsa, 'SocketArray') {
    $DB::single = 1;
    1;
}
```

fixed it, and the debugger stopped at `1;` when it triggered.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do that. It breaks at the next breakable line.

Consider the following program.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

print "hello";

for my $foo ( 1.. 10 ) {
    print "$foo\n";
    if ($foo == 9) {
        $DB::single = 1;
    }
}
```

There's a conditional breakpoint when `$foo` is 9. The breakpoint gets set after the `print`. It turns the breaks on, but it only stops at the next breakable line, which is the `print` line for when `$foo` is 10.

```
$ perl -d breaking.pl

Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.51
Editor support available.

Enter h or 'h h' for help, or 'man perldebug' for more help.

main::(breaking.pl:4):  print "hello";
  DB<1> r
hello1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
main::(breaking.pl:7):      print "$foo\n";
  DB<1> l
7==>        print "$foo\n";
8:      if ($foo == 9) {
9:          $DB::single = 1;
10      }
11  }
12  
  DB<1> x $foo
0  10
  DB<2> r
10
Debugged program terminated.  Use q to quit or R to restart,
```

So you need to do your check at the top of whatever it is you want to inspect.

Comment: Wouldn't be the trick to add some dummy statement (like `1;`) right after `$DB::single = 1;` then?

Comment: You can even make do without the `if` statement as in `$DB::single = $foo == 9` or `$DB:single = $ENV{RUN_IN_DEBUGGER}`.

Comment: @simbabque, but do you know why the postfix if syntax does not break as stated in the question (and I can confirm that).

Comment: @GuidoFlohr I don't know, no.

Comment: @Guido Flohr
Works fine for me. If you have a question, please post it as a question and include a minimal, runable demonstration of the problem. I shouldn't have to guess at what you did.

Comment: @ikegami I had a typo. It works with postfix if, sorry for the confusion.